# How to select students with repeated low scores?

Tags: c#, linq

Scores are considered low if they are less than or equal to 5. I want to select students with repeated low scores.

The expected result is:

```
Andy 
Bobby
Cindy
```

As each of them has repeated low scores.

#### Question

I got stuck in completing the last expression `GroupBy` in the `Where` clause.
Could you make it done?

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<int> Scores { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public static List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name="Andy",
                Scores={1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name="Bobby",
                Scores={3,3,3,3,4,5}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name="Cindy",
                Scores={1,1,2,2,3,4,5}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name="Dave",
                Scores={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
            }
        };
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var query = Student.GetStudents()
                           .Where(s => s.Scores.GroupBy(i => i).????);
            

        foreach (var x in query)
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
var query = Student.GetStudents()
                           .Where(s => s.Scores
                                        .Where(x => x <= 5)
                                        .GroupBy(i => i)
                                        .Any(x => x.Count() > 1));
```

Comment: The more readable won. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
           var query = Student.GetStudents()
                               .Select(x => new { student = x.Name, scores = x.Scores.GroupBy(y => y).Select(y => new { score = y.Key, count = y.Count() }).ToList() }).ToList();

            var lowScore = query.Where(x => x.scores.Any(y => (y.count > 1) && (y.score <= 5))).ToList();
```